# Custom TableViewController producing blank cells

Tags: swift, list, tableview, cells

I've been following along with Apple's Swift Education Book, and I'm creating a ToDo list. I created my own, had this problem so I ripped up all my code until I ended up with an exact copy, line for line of Apple's.

It's producing blank cells with my TableViewController subclass.

```
class ToDoTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var todos = [ToDo]()
```

In my TableViewController (which is linked in the storyboard), there's two overrides; one dequeues and the other returns the count of the rows in a section to be all the rows.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                           numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return todos.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt
    indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
            "ToDoCellIdentifier") else {
                fatalError("Could not dequeue a cell")
    }

    let todo = todos[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = todo.title
    return cell
}
```

Then a viewDidLoad override so that I could insert sample items.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let savedToDos = ToDo.loadToDos() {
        todos = savedToDos
    } else {
        ToDo.loadSampleToDos()
    }
}
```

*Xcode says these are unused.*

My other file is a ToDo class, with titles, due dates etc and my sample data:

```
class ToDo: NSObject {

    var title: String
    var isComplete: Bool
    var dueDate: Date
    var notes: String?

init(title: String, isComplete: Bool, dueDate: Date, notes:
    String?) {

    guard !title.isEmpty else {
        fatalError("Reminder requires a non-empty title")
    }

    self.title = title
    self.isComplete = isComplete
    self.dueDate = dueDate
    self.notes = notes
}
```

And the sample data in the file:

```
static func loadSampleToDos() -> [ToDo] {
    let todo1 = ToDo(title: "ToDo One", isComplete: false,
                     dueDate: Date(), notes: "Notes 1")
    let todo2 = ToDo(title: "ToDo Two", isComplete: false,
                     dueDate: Date(), notes: "Notes 2")
    let todo3 = ToDo(title: "ToDo Three", isComplete: false,
                     dueDate: Date(), notes: "Notes 3")

    return [todo1, todo2, todo3]
}
```

I've set the cell identifier to "ToDoCellIdentifier" in the storyboard.

Run it, there's only blank cells. Why are they blank?

Comment: where you display the todo values in the cell?

Comment: [Edit] your question with the complete `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: @Ragul do you mean? var todos = [ToDo]()

Comment: cell.textLabel?.text = "Your display text here"

Comment: reload the tableView after assigning values to todos

Comment: It currently says `cell.textLabel?.text = todo.title`, @Ragul. Is that wrong? I'm not wanting a static string to be the text label.

Comment: Thats okay. try reloading the tableView after assigning values to todos in ViewDidLoad()

Comment: tableView.reloadData() add this line at the end of ViewDidLoad()

Comment: I put that in the static function. It's still blank.

Comment: no add the line at the end of ViewDidLoad()

Comment: I did that. `    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let savedToDos = ToDo.loadToDos() {
            todos = savedToDos
        } else {
            todos = ToDo.loadSampleToDos()
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
` Doesn't work, still.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148976/discussion-between-yeeeeee-and-ragul).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let savedToDos = ToDo.loadToDos() {
        todos = savedToDos
    } else {
        todos = ToDo.loadSampleToDos()
    }
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return todos.count
}
```

Comment: Still produces blank cells. I'm using the developer preview of Swift 4 if that makes a difference to my circumstances...

Comment: did you implement `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)`? post more code for question can help us to find out problem. @yeeeeee

Comment: Sorry..what is OP?

Comment: The original post.

Comment: but i just saw `class ToDoTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var todos = [ToDo]()`

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean

Comment: You say you updated complete project but I haven't saw it! I haven't saw you implement `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: It's there now @Codus

Comment: Did you set the tableview delegate and datasource?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149062/discussion-between-yeeeeee-and-codus).